# Is possible to have a vm running linux that require no installation on windows?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines

I want to create a self contained VM that reside in a folder on a windows computer.

When running, it requires no installation of VM software; and can run in the background, so I can send from Windows for example, files to be parsed (the idea is to send scripts made in python, c++ or shell script and get back the result after the scripts are compiled and executed)

Is this possible? I am working on a training program where users can learn to program in different languages, and in a totally sealed environment so they won't mess up their machines while experimenting.

The only thing I found are either single board hardware devices, running linux, or VM images that are big (I don't need anything but the compilers for the 3 languages and the base Linux OS) and require you to install VMWare or other similar software.

Comment: You have to have something installed to run virtual machines!

Comment: I understand that; but couldn't it be already in the same folder in which the VM file is located? I would llike to have something that I can just place on a folder in documents for example, and when done, delete it

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Some kind of hypervisor must actually be installed and loaded at boot time. You can't do that with a "portable" setup.

Comment: I see, so conceptually there is no way to put everything in a folder and run it locally on a machine, without install any software. Thanks for the info; I will need to find an alternative way to do this then,

Comment: If you can boot from USB, then a Linux live system with persistence (for additional software/user directories) might work for you. There you can install virtualization software like VirtualBox if needed. Fast USB3.0 drives are cheap nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a browser to emulate Linux. There are some distributions that include compilers and executable to interpreted languages like python and perl.

Some examples:

- [Terminals from CodingGround](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_terminal_online.php)
- [JSlinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/)
- [Webterminal](http://www.webminal.org/)

Have fun and happy coding!

Comment: This is an interesting solution; it require to be connected to the outside network; which I was not planning to, for our training sessions, but seems much easier to script a browser to point to these browser installations ! Is there a way to run one of these locally? I could easily set up a system that trigger a web server running on the local machine, which would host the linux terminal.

I don't mind to spend efforts in coding the setup, as long as I can run it locally. Otherwise, I can leverage on the online solution, although then there are issues related to safety and security.

Comment: There is an open source solution called http://copy.sh/. You could download it and run it local.

Answer (score 1):

You could run [Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux) or [Windows containers on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10), an option for isolated, self contained, lightweight environments. It does require Hyper-V + docker, so does not meet your no install requirement.

Or, consider running a CI/CD type service were you centrally host the build/test/deploy infrastructure. Reproducible builds, but tricky to scale to a classroom of people, and developers still need a local environment to debug things.

Comment: Indeed; the options here are all very involved, and require me to actually tap in the computers to set them up; versus just give a folder with everything in it and double click on the app to run the VM. Thanks for your insights

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do that in a VM without installing a hypervisor of some sort, but modern Windows versions provide the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) that might be used in the way you describe if you set up a user friendly wrapper to send files between the user’s directory and the WSL working directory. Another alternative might be to run Cygwin that also provides a Unix-like shell in Windows.

Both require installation, but are significantly less resource intensive than a hypervisor+VM.

Comment: How close to the "real thin" would WSL be? Can I use apt-get or other package managers to run on and install things like python or GCC?

Comment: To be honest I've only tested WSL for a few minutes on a borrowed Win 10 laptop when my Mac was being serviced, so I haven't got a lot of experience with it. But yes, if you install WSL and the Ubuntu package you can run apt-get to install programs pretty much as you'd expect. Links to Microsoft's own information: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/wsl-guideline/9n73v46804z8?activetab=pivot:overviewtab, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q?activetab=pivot:overviewtab